# Skype integration with python desktop app

Tags: python-2.7, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

i have made a python desktop app which takes voice commands now i want to present it via Skype to someone and so i want the people to hear the response , is there a way to do it, so that everyone on the call can hear the response and give voice command to it..

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no way to present content through the Skype Web SDK. This might be something we add in a future release.